# Lookahead assertion as condition in conditional subpattern on .NET regular expression

Tags: php, .net, regex, pcre

I have this huge RegEx for matching credit cards numbers. But its PCRE. Works flawlessly in PHP.

```
/(\d{13,16})(?(?=<)<|["']).*?(?=(?(?=>)>|["\'])\d{3,4}(?(?=<)<|["']))(?(?=>)>|["'])(\d{3,4})(?(?=<)<|["'])/is
// /i = ignore case
// /s = treat the subject as a single line
```

I convert it to .NET. Just added `@` at the beginning and double the double quotes. I think its the proper procedure.

```
@"(\d{13,16})(?(?=<)<|[""]).*?(?=(?(?=>)>|[""])\d{3,4}(?(?=<)<|[""]))(?(?=>)>|[""])(\d{3,4})(?(?=<)<|[""])"
```

Now it doesn't match. I know PCRE and .NET implementation might not be same. But I think I can convert it to compatible one. I look up on [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). It seems my pattern has nothing special which could be PCRE specific.

After analyzing the pattern I found the `(?(?=<)<|[""])` is not matching!. So made the regular expression simpler. Its now `@"(?(?=q)qu|\w)\w+"`. And I am matching against `"Queen, Quick, Qi etc"`

### PHP

#### Code

```
$data =  "Queen, Quick, Qi etc";
$pattern = "(?(?=q)qu|\w)\w+";
preg_match_all("/$pattern/is", $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Queen
            [1] => Quick
            [2] => etc
        )
)
```

### C# .NET

#### Code

```
        string data = "Queen, Quick, Qi etc";
        string pattern = @"(?(?=q)qu|\w)\w+";
        Regex re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match m in re.Matches(data))
        {
            if (m.Success)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Credit Card Number={0}, CCV={1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[6].Value);
                for (int i = 1; i < m.Groups.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}]", i, m.Groups[i].Value);
                    for (int j = 0; j < m.Groups[i].Captures.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}][{2}]", i, m.Groups[i].Value, m.Groups[i].Captures[j].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

#### Output

```
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Output is nothing.

My questions are

1. Does look-ahead assertion as condition in conditional sub-pattern work on .NET regular expression?
2. How can I modify the simpler regular expression `@"(?(?=q)qu|\w)\w+"` so that it matches just like PHP in .NET?
3. On the first regex (the huge one) on .NET, is there anything I can apply so it matches just like PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.: Conditionals work in .NET just as they do in PHP.

2.: The "simpler" regex is correct for .NET. You're just using it wrong:

You have no capturing groups in your regex. That means that the loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < m.Groups.Count; i++) {...}
```

is never executed because `m.Groups.Count` is 1.

The correct way would be something like

```
foreach (Match m in re.Matches(data))
{
   if (m.Success)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < m.Groups.Count; i++) // Groups are numbered from zero
       {
           // Groups[0] is the entire match
           Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}]", i, m.Groups[i].Value);
       }
   }
}
```

3.: Your regex is missing the single quotes.

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(\d{13,16})(?(?=<)<|[""']).*?(?=(?(?=>)>|[""'])\d{3,4}(?(?=<)<|[""']))(?(?=>)>|[""'])(\d{3,4})(?(?=<)<|[""'])", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

would be a literal translation.

4.: You don't need the `/i` or `Ignorecase` parameter as there are no letters in your regex.

5.: `(?(?=<)<|["'])` makes no sense. It matches exactly the same text as `[<"']`. After all it means "if there is a `<`, then match a `<`. Otherwise, try to match a `"` or a `'`. There is no need to use a conditional regex at all.

So the entire regex can be simplified to

```
(\d{13,16})[<"'].*?(?=[>"']\d{3,4}[<"'])[>"'](\d{3,4})[<"']
```

6.: This shows another superfluous part of the regex more clearly: You have a lookahead assertion `(?=[>"']\d{3,4}[<"'])` that is followed by the exact same regex `[>"'](\d{3,4})[<"']`, so the lookahead can be dropped entirely.

End result:

```
(\d{13,16})[<"'].*?[>"'](\d{3,4})[<"']
```

or, in C#:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(\d{13,16})[<""'].*?[>""'](\d{3,4})[<""']", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```